# Why flutter don't detect the tables of my prepopulated sqlite database? (1) no such table

Tags: flutter, sqlite, exception, error-handling

I have a prepopulated database in the assets of my app. The app makes the connection with the database properly, but when I try to make a simple rawQuery like ("Select * FROM empresa") it throw me an exception saying the table doesn't exist.

What can generate this problem and more important, how can I fix it?

This is the code of my class DBHelper. I only make an instance of this class in other page and there is the error.

```
    class DBHelper {
      static Database? _db;

      Future<Database> get db async => _db ??= await initDB();

      initDB() async {
        Directory documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        String path = join(documentDirectory.path, "ANUARIO.db");
        bool dbExists = await File(path).exists();
        if (!dbExists) {
           try {
             ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(join("assets", "ANUARIO.db"));
             List<int> bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
             await File(path).writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
         } catch (e) {
             print(e);
        }
        }

        var theDB = await openDatabase(path);
        return theDB;
        }

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

u must share ur code to see what go wrong with it

but i think that u create the same data base over every time u run ur function

and for example u must see if there is any database with the same name have been create before and if it create before do not create new one and make query

and u can use this may be helpful

[sqflite_ffi.dart](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite_common_ffi)

Comment: It makes sense what you say. But I still don't get it in the code. I'm new in flutter and I'm still learning so probably there are things I'm overlooking.